# how to know if a .ts segment is audio-only segment?

Tags: android, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, multimedia

HTTP Live Streaming supports .ts format, if a streaming source is audio-only source and it is packed in .ts segment and the m3u8 file doesn't contain CODECS attribute. So, how can I know if this stream is audio-only or audio-video source?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for some code, or a tool? Do you need to do this once, or automate it? Can you download a segment and examine it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) or [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) to determine if the segment contains a video and/or audio stream.

Note that if you use Apple's `mediafilesegmenter` tool (with the `-a` option) to create an audio-only stream it generates `.aac` files, so if it is a `.ts` file then it *probably* does contain both video and audio.